# Python ast: decide whether a FunctionDef is inside a ClassDef or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd like to build an ast from a Python source code, then get specific information from the ast. I faced the following problem: while walking through a ClassDef's body is viable, how I decide if a method is inside the class or not.

The code I build ast from:

```py
class A:
    def foo(self):
        pass


def foo(self):
    pass
```

In this example I will hit all the `foo`s but I will not able to tell if it is from the class or not (as they have the same set of parameters, named badly, but the code can be interpreted).

```py
    def build_ast(self):
        with open(self.path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
            tree = ast.parse(fp.read())
            for node in ast.walk(tree):
                if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
                    print(ast.dump(node))
                    # access the parent if it has
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally satisfied with my final solution, but apparently it works for Python 3.8.3:

As I experienced, `ast.walk` traverses ClassDef nodes before FunctionsDef nodes.

```py
def build_ast(self):
    with open(self.path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        tree = ast.parse(fp.read())

        for node in ast.walk(tree):
            if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
                if hasattr(node, "parent"):
                    print(node.parent.name, node.name)
                else:
                    print(node.name, "is not in a class.")
            if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef):
                for child in node.body:
                    if isinstance(child, ast.FunctionDef):
                        child.parent = node
```

Comment: Just wondering, in above code snipping what kind of functions would be ignored, I think  ```ast.AsyncFunctionDef```  should be added, anything else based on your experience and knowledge

Comment: The first of the if clauses fails for nested methods and decorator methods, you will have to be more specific about the parent testing, testing for classes explicitly. And probably consider decorator classes as well.